# About friend function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++, friend-function

Sales_data.h

```
#ifndef SALES_DATA_H
#define SALES_DATA_H
#include <string>

class Sales_data {
    friend std::istream &read(std::istream &in, Sales_data &data);
    friend std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out, const Sales_data &data);

public:
    Sales_data() = default;
    //Sales_data(std::string _bookNo="", unsigned _units_sold = 0, double _revenue = 0)
        //:bookNo(_bookNo), units_sold(_units_sold), revenue(_revenue) {}
    std::string isbn() { return bookNo; }
    Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);
    double avg_price() const;
private:
    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0;
};

Sales_data &Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data& data) {
    units_sold += data.units_sold;
    revenue += data.revenue;
    return *this;
}

std::istream &read(std::istream &in, Sales_data &data);
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out, const Sales_data &data);

#endif
```

Sales_data.cpp

```
#include "Sales_data.h"

/*
double Sales_data::avg_price() const {
    return units_sold != 0 ? (revenue / units_sold) : 0;
}
*/

std::istream &read(std::istream &in, Sales_data &data) {
    in >> data.bookNo >> data.units_sold >> data.revenue;
    return in;
}

std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out, Sales_data &data) {
    out << data.isbn() << " " << data.units_sold << " " << data.revenue;
    return out;
}
```

main_func.cpp

```
#include "Sales_data.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

void func() {
    Sales_data total;
    if(read(cin, total)) {
        Sales_data trans;
        while(read(cin, trans)) {
            if (total.isbn() == trans.isbn())
                total.combine(trans);
            else {
                print(cout, total) << endl;
                total = trans;
            }
        }
        print(cout, total) << endl;
    } else {
        cerr << "No data?!" << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I run the programs, but it always tell me there is something wrong. And I do use the friend function, but it still says i use the private member of the class. The info as fllow:

`Sales_data.cpp:10:23: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_istream<char>' and 'unsigned int')
    in >> data.bookNo >> data.units_sold >> data.revenue;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'unsigned int'
    operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
    ^
Sales_data.cpp:15:24: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'const char *')
    out << data.isbn() << " " << data.units_sold << " " << data.revenue;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2753:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'char const[2]'
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
    ^
Sales_data.cpp:15:39: error: 'units_sold' is a private member of 'Sales_data'
    out << data.isbn() << " " << data.units_sold << " " << data.revenue;
                                      ^
./Sales_data.h:18:14: note: declared private here
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
             ^
Sales_data.cpp:15:65: error: 'revenue' is a private member of 'Sales_data'
    out << data.isbn() << " " << data.units_sold << " " << data.revenue;
                                                                ^
./Sales_data.h:19:12: note: declared private here
    double revenue = 0;
           ^
4 errors generated.`

Comment: You forgot to include `<iostream>`

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thank you, I do forget to include the file.

Comment: Also the `combine` function must not be defined in the .h file, otherwise you get linkage duplication error. So move it to .cpp or make it inline.

Comment: @Zoka Hive fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Sales_data &` and `const Sales_data &` are different types, the `print` function in your cpp file is considered a separate *overload* of the `print` function, which is *not* a friend of your `Sales_data` class.

Add `const` back to fix this error:

```
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out, const Sales_data &data) {
... //                                 ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: To have the proposed solution working, you also needs to make isbn function const too: `std::string  isbn() const { return bookNo; }` (by making the function `const` you say, that calling this function does not changes any internal data of the class.

Comment: I compile the program with the command `clang++ 8.6.cpp Sales_data.cpp  -std=c++11`, but it tells me `/tmp/Sales_data-08bdcf.o: In function `Sales_data::combine(Sales_data const&)':    
Sales_data.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Sales_data::combine(Sales_data const&)'    
/tmp/8-b9582d.o:8.6.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here    
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @Sparks_Fly The second error is there because you put the implementation of `combine` into the header, but outside the class declaration. You should either move it into the declaration, or move it to the cpp file.

Comment: @Zoka You're right technically, but since the objective appears to be demonstrating friendship, the real error here is using "data.isbn()", instead of "data.bookNo". As a friend, the print() function can access private data.bookNo, but calling data.isbn() fails, because, in print(), data is a const reference and so only const member functions may be called - as you pointed out.